# Fatal error during command execution (MySQL, VBNET)

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, vb.net

Tengo un problema al insertar unos datos desde una aplicacion VB.Net a una base de datos Mysql, el problema que tengo lo han preguntado muchas otras personas pero no puedo encontrar que exactamente que es en lo que falla mi codigo

```vb
Function Guardar_Datos() As Boolean
    Dim err As Boolean = False
    Dim con As New MySqlConnection
    Dim captura As String = "" 
    con.ConnectionString = server
    Try
        con.Open()
        Try



            For f As Integer = 0 To DataGridView1.RowCount - 1
                captura = "INSERT INTO estatusdeot.presupuestos (`Presupuesto`, `Obra`, `Cliente`, `Direccion`, `Atencion`, [Ruta de Archivo], `Cotizo`, `Factor`, [Monto Ppto.], `Fecha`)" & _
                     "VALUES (@Presupuesto, @Obra, @Cliente, @Direccion, @Atencion, @RutadeArchivo, @Cotizo, @Factor, @MontoPpto, @Fecha);"
                Dim insertar As New MySqlCommand(captura, con)
                'insertar.Prepare()

                insertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Presupuesto", DataGridView1.Item(0, f).Value)
                insertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Obra", DataGridView1.Item(1, f).Value.ToString)
                insertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cliente", DataGridView1.Item(2, f).Value.ToString)
                insertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Direnccion", DataGridView1.Item(3, f).Value.ToString)
                insertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Atencion", DataGridView1.Item(4, f).Value.ToString)
                insertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RutadeArchivo", DataGridView1.Item(5, f).Value.ToString)
                insertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Cotizo", DataGridView1.Item(6, f).Value.ToString)
                insertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Factor", DataGridView1.Item(7, f).Value)
                insertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MontoPpto", DataGridView1.Item(8, f).Value)
                insertar.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Fecha", DataGridView1.Item(9, f).Value.ToString)
                insertar.ExecuteNonQuery()
            Next
            err = False
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox(ex.Message)
            err = True
        End Try
        con.Close()
        con.Dispose()
    Catch exc As Exception
        MsgBox("hubo un error al conectar con servidor " & vbCrLf & exc.Message, vbCritical)
    End Try
    Return err
End Function
```

El campo Presupuesto y el Campo Factor estan como Int(11) y el campo Monto esta como Decimal(15,2).

Gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Prueba a poner los nombres de columnas que tienen espacios entre corchetes (`[Ruta de Archivo]` por ejemplo) y en los parámetros quita los espacios en blanco (`@RutadeArchivo`), tanto en la consulta como en los `AddWithValue`

Comment: hice lo que me dijiste y no funciono, probe con [Ruta de Archivo] y `Ruta de Archivo` tambien quite los espacios en el query @RutadeArchivo y en los addwithvalue @RutadeArchivo y no me funciono tambien con [Monto Ppto.]